# avoid quotes when passing variable into php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have (from database):

```
<?php
$l = array();
$l['lat'] = $row['lat']; //51.507351
$l['lon'] = $row['lon']; //-0.127758
$l['animation'] = $row['animation']; //google.maps.Animation.DROP - stored without quotes in database
?>
```

If I var_dump($l):

```
array(3) { ["lat"]=> string(9) "51.507351" ["lon"]=> string(9) "-0.127758" ["animation"]=> string(26) "google.maps.Animation.DROP" }
```

Then "google.maps.Animation.DROP" is in quotes. How to avoid that? lat and lon must be in quotes. How to force that animation is not string?

**Edit:**
I want to achieve that (using Twig and json_encode) - google.maps.Animation.DROP and this should be without quotes:

```
var l = {{ l|json_encode|raw }};
$(function() {
      new Maplace({
        show_markers: true,
        locations: [l],

    }).Load();
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it have quotes? What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe because it's a string?!

Comment: The string doesn't ACTUALLY have quotes around it (if you echo it you'll see that), it just displays that way in a var dump because it's a string.

Comment: All strings are put in quotes when var_dumped.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the question is based on a misunderstanding of the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a javascript object reference that way in json since json has to be string.

My suggestion would be to just pass the string `"DROP"` and then in javascript use `[]` object notation.

```
var animation =  google.maps.Animation[ myData.animation];
```

This would be the equivalent to:

```
var animation =  google.maps.Animation[ "DROP"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it server side, just loop for the array and cast the animation field from string to decimal, then use the edited array instead of the one you directly receive from the database .

To convert a type from string to float in php you can use :
floatval function , details can be found here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php